# Arrayformula to return words from a dictionary in multiple phrases

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm struggling to get an arrayformula to do this:

- Find in the list or phrases (Phrases!A2:A) the words/parts of the sentence that are included in the dictionary (Dictionary!A2:A). With regexmatch to find not only words but also parts of the sentence.
- Return the "Words to return" (Dictionary!B2:B) separated by ; (don't include ; is just 1 word is found).
- Using lambda function (BYROW) would be better than ARRAYFORMULA I suppose

Here is the example document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OOcqI2MntYiNw9PoHGEgemahIJPwWa770S9SCv6_ikE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: there is no `blue` word in row 2 input but expected o/p is shown as `sky`??!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow That's true, spreadsheet is now corrected

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;textjoin("; ";1;index(xlookup(split(Σ;" ");Dictionary!A:A;Dictionary!B:B;))))))
```

[image]

*`logic`: split up the sentence → lookup each word in dictionary → join all returned matches*

***formula for updated scenario***:

```js
=map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;textjoin("; ";1;choosecols(reduce(;Dictionary!A2:index(Dictionary!A:A;match(;0/(Dictionary!A:A<>"")));
     lambda(a;c;iferror(let(Λ;search(c;Σ);sort(vstack(a;hstack(Λ;if(Λ;offset(c;;1);))))))));2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a more regexmatch-like formula, being able to add parts of the phrases in the "word to find" column. For example "red net" instead of just "red". Sorry for this error in the post, I'm going to edit it.

Comment: do test the updated answer

Comment: it works well, but I get this error with 3000 rows: "Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula". It's a heavy performance formula, there is another workaround to achieve the same results? I don't mind if it's a drag formula instead map/arrayformula. thank you very much for your help

Comment: Change `map(A2:A;` → `map(A2;` and `Dictionary!A2` → `Dictionary!A$2` then drag down the formula. Also wait n' see if anyone pitches in with an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the words returned is not important, you could try:

```
=arrayformula(let(
phrases;tocol(A2:A;1);
searchfor;tocol(Dictionary!A2:A;1);
return;tocol(Dictionary!B2:B;1);
matrix;if(iferror(search(transpose(searchfor);phrases));transpose(return););
substitute(trim(tocol(query(transpose(matrix);;9^9)));" ";"; ")))
```

For the example given it will return 'apple; grass' rather than 'grass; apple'.

This is using a 2D `arrayformula` to transform the `search` result for each search word against the list of phrases into a matrix of the equivalent return words, then employing an old trick abusing the way `query` processes headers to concatenate the matrix into the required format. I obviously can't test how well this works on your longer list, however it doesn't use `lambdas` so in theory shouldn't run into problems with calculation limits (although it may still be very slow)